# SSH times out when using a VPN. Works fine inside my network

Tags: networking, router, ssh, vpn, openssh

I have an Ubuntu server running in my network. When I SSH inside my network, it works fine. If I try to do it outside of my local network — connected to a VPN — I cannot reach it (times out).

It's also only this IP, other ip's are perfectly reachable. I tried setting up the firewall for port 22 on both my router (where the VPN lives) and on the server, and forwarding the port on my router, no success.

What can I do?

Comment: How is the VPN configured? Traceroute? What have you done to figure out where the problem is occurring in your network or setup?

Comment: Hi, was about to post this today. I found out that all the IP's are not available (so not only the Ubuntu one). The VPN is a Synology VPN plus, installed on my Synology router. So I guess the problem lies there. The only thing is that it has always worked until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Apparently my router gave me a 172.x.x.x IP instead of the 192.168.x.x, after an upgrade. Turned the new switch to 'local IP' so it gave me an IP from my local network and the problem was solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, the autocorrect turned the word switch into seeing :-)